# Copying namespaces in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I'm trying to construct a new element based on an old one, including copying in its children. To prevent each child from repeating the namespace definitions for each namespace in scope, I'm interested in copying the namespace declarations as well.

Namespace declarations aren't picked up as regular attributes through `$element/@*`.

If I restrict my code to only work with XQuery 3.0, I can do the following:

```
<new-element>
  {
    for $ns-prefix in in-scope-prefixes($element)
    let $ns-uri := namespace-uri-for-prefix($ns-prefix, $element)
    return namespace { $ns-prefix } { $ns-uri }
  }
  ...
</new-element>
```

Is there a better way?

---

To clarify the problem a bit -- my original document looks like so:

```
<root xmlns:stuff="...">
  <child name="foo"/>
  <child name="bar"/>
</root>
```

When I copy children into a new document, I get the following:

```
<new-element>
  <child xmlns:stuff="..." name="foo"/>
  <child xmlns:stuff="..." name="bar"/>
</new-element>
```

...whereas it would make more sense to simply attach the `xmlns:stuff` declaration to `<new-element>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you permit use of XQuery Update, you could use a transform expression (copy/modify/return) to copy the node, then modify the name.

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 3.0, the following should work if your implementation supports the namespace axis (which I believe is an optional feature):

```
<new-element>
 {$element/namespace::*}
 ...
</new-element>
```

Comment: Well, the XPath spec says it is officially deprecated: "As of XPath 2.0, the namespace axis is deprecated and need not be supported by a host language. A host language that does not support the namespace axis need not represent namespace bindings in the form of nodes." (Just a few lines above the heading of 2.1) http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-basics . A shame to my opinion by the way.

Comment: @grtjn: This is one of the many reasons I prefer XSLT to XQuery :)

Comment: Of course, what @grtjn quoted also applies to XSLT :)  What you are looking for is an easy way to copy all the in-scope namespaces (rather than the namespace declarations).  I personally would wrap your FLWOR expression as a new function `local:in-scope-namespaces($arg as node())`

Comment: "The argument against namespace is that it complicates the implementation of nodes, and it may be difficult to avoid overhead even for XQuery code that does not use the namespace axis. This is a high cost for a rarely-used feature, so it is not included in XQuery." — Per Bothner, 2003 ([xml.com](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/10/xquery.html))

Answer (score 0):

If you use programmatic constructors, I believe they take care of the namespace declarations in the way you need.

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare function local:transform($node)
{
  typeswitch($node)
  case element()
    return element { fn:node-name($node) } {
      $node/@*,
      for $n in $node/*
      return local:transform($n)
    }
  default return $node
};

let $node :=
  <dmc:root xmlns:dmc="http://davidcassel.net/dmc">
    <dmc:parent attr="value">
      <stuff:child xmlns:stuff="http://davidcassel.net/stuff">some text</stuff:child>
    </dmc:parent>
  </dmc:root>
return local:transform($node)
```

Running that produces

```
<dmc:root xmlns:dmc="http://davidcassel.net/dmc">
  <dmc:parent attr="value">
    <stuff:child xmlns:stuff="http://davidcassel.net/stuff"/>
  </dmc:parent>
</dmc:root>
```

Add cases to the typeswitch to make the structural changes you want. Does that accomplish what you're looking for?

Tested on MarkLogic 5 using standard XQuery 1.0.

Comment: Added some clarifications to the question -- basically, getting `xmlns:stuff` defined on each child is what I'm trying to avoid, when attaching it to the new version of the parent would be more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and simply added a "fake" attribute to the parent node in the namespace, which causes it to pick up the declaration at that level.

```
<new-element stuff:something="anything">
  ...

</new-element>
```